# Congruence involving Bernoulli numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, bernoulli-numbers

I need to show that $$2B_{2m}\equiv1\pmod{4}$$ for $m\ge2.$ This should be something easy using (at most) Claussen and von Staudt's theorem, but I haven't been successful yet. Writing $B_{2m}=U_{2m}/V_{2m},(U_{2m},V_{2m})=1,V_{2m}>0$ I know $$V_{2m}\equiv2U_{2m}\pmod4,$$
but since $2\mid V_{2m},$ this is not very useful. I also wanted to try Hensel's lifting lemma for $f(x)=2x-1$ (because $2B_{2m}\equiv1\pmod2$ holds), but $f'(x)\equiv0\pmod2,$ so this is not the right way as well. Any other tips?

*Remark.* I needed this result for finishing the following problem.

> Let $q$ be a prime number such that $2q+1$ is composite. Show that the numerator of the Bernoulli number $B_{2q}$ is divisible by a prime of the form $4n+3$.

The congruence mentioned above is a final step in my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $n\geq 2$
$$0=2\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom {2n+1}kB_k=1-2n+\binom{2n+1}{2}\frac{1}{3}+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\binom{2n+1}{2k}(2B_{2k})+(2n+1)(2B_{2n}).$$
Now if $2B_{2m}\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ for $m=2,\dots,n-1$ then
$$(2n+1)(2B_{2n})\equiv -1+2n-3\binom{2n+1}{2}
-\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\binom{2n+1}{2k}\\=-4^n-4n^2+2n+1\equiv 2n+1\pmod{4}.$$
and, since $(2n+1)$ is odd, it follows that $2B_{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: Am I missing something? Taking your equality $\mathrm{mod}\ 4$ I get $0\equiv-2m+(m+1)(2m+1)(3+(2B_{2m}))$ (since $3\cdot3\equiv1$) which works perfectly for even $m.$ But e.g. $m\equiv3$ gives $0\equiv-6$ which is not true, obviously.

Comment: @byk7 For $n=3$, the RHS is $-6+(28/3)-(14/3)+(4/3)\equiv -6-0+14-0\equiv 0$.

Comment: Ok, I received $(n+1)(2n+1)\equiv(n+1)(2n+1)(2B_{2n}),$ which is still problematic for $n\equiv3$...

Comment: @byk7 I revised my answer. Now it should work.

Comment: I received the same, thx. :)

Answer (score 2):

By [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) for the $2m$-th powers,$$2^{2m}+1=\frac1{2m+1}\left(2^{2m+1}+\frac{2^{2m}}2+\cdots
+(2m+1)2B_{2m}\right).$$
All terms but the term are multiples of $4$ so we get $1\equiv 2B_{2m}
\pmod4$.